# cannot see branches after git fetch

Tags: git, git-fetch

I try to make git fetch, but after the command is completed, it doesn't expose any info in the console. git config --get remote.origin.fetch says:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

?

Comment: The `git fetch` command isn’t supposed to print most of the information to the terminal. It updates the Git repository; specifically, it downloads the commits from the remote repository and updates the refs in `refs/remotes/origin/` to point to the new commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a git fetch returns an *empty* output, the most likely reason is:

your local cloned repository *already* has the all history of the remote repo cloned.
There is nothing new to fetch.